# Are there any good frameworks for making mobile friendly HTML forms?

Tags: html, css, frameworks, touch

I'm making a website with lot's of forms, designed for mobile use (small screens).

Are there any frameworks available that are really focused on user friendly forms for mobile with touch? Meaning BIG buttons, easy to size elements and fit as much on the screen as possible? More like native apps?

I've tried Twitter Bootstrap, but it's simply not very userfriendly for phones.

Comment: Did you use class for mobile resolution? (col-xs-6 for example)
Did you try use the media queries?

Answer (score 2):

You can try http://goratchet.com

Bootstrap Mobile version

Answer (score 1):

You could give [Tacit](https://yegor256.github.io/tacit/) a try. It's a class-less CSS framework were all you need is just a single `<link>` statement in your HTML and the web page will have a finished look. It works out of the box with both Desktop and Mobile and you don't need to assign a class to the standard HTML elements, in particular to the usual elements you'd use in a form.

Here are a few examples of pages that use Tacit, and the only work put into was including the CSS file: http://filfreire.com/, http://www.jare.io/, https://socatar.com/